# kohana check if image is available before rendering

Tags: php, image, kohana

I have pictures readed in foreach loop. I need to check if picture can be readed from folder and show it. If picture is not in folder or can't be readed  have to print some message.  So in followng code:

```
foreach($pictures as $picture){
if(is on disk in proper folder and can be readed properly){
    echo HTML::image($picture);
}
else{
    echo "can't read the picure";
}
```

}

how to check if picture is on disk in proper folder and can be readed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 foreach($pictures as $picture){
        if(file_exists($picture)){
           echo '<img src="'.$picture.'" />';
        }
        else{
            echo "can't read the picure";
        }
    }
```